# How can I scroll screen or tmux buffer without pausing the application?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux, scrolling

I want to have the same behavior as <kbd>C-A</kbd>/<kbd>C-B</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> provides except i want to be able to return to my application to see that it has progressed in her calculations or has not disconnected to the server because of timeout.

I've been told it's impossible because applications tend to keep modifying the buffer, but can't this be circumvented by, uh, actually modifying the buffer, or creating a temporary buffer?

Answer (score 5):

You can capture the pane with the `capture-pane` tmux command. Just type:

```
Ctrl+b
:capture-pane
```

The contents of the pane will be saved in a new buffer (or an existing one with the `-b` switch). The `-S` switch (starting line number) will also be useful if you want to capture lines outside the current screen. Negative numbers to `-S` specify lines above the current screen.

Then you can use the `list-buffers` and `show-buffer` commands to see the contents.